# Unable to get a list by name with a hyphen

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

Trying to upload a file to a folder in a SP Online where the title is "Forms - May" and set some of the fields. I can't seem to get the list or any of the fields. The list and the folder definitely exist. I can get other lists and folders without hyphens which is why I'm assuming this is the problem - is there a special way I need to handle this? I have tried to load the list into the client context which also breaks it. The specific error occurs when I try to get the fields in the list. This is wrapped in a try/catch and the exception I get is File Not Found

```
Web web = clientContext.Web;
List forms = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Forms - May");
string destination = "Forms - May/Folder1";

FileCreationInformation flciNewFile = new FileCreationInformation();
var targetFolder = clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(dest);    
var uFolder = targetFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile);

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile);

var listItem = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
Field field = forms.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("FieldInternalName");
clientContext.Load(field, f => f.TypeAsString);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  //breaks
```

Comment: try using relative path(url) of list `ctx.Web.GetList("sites/dev/lists/Forms - May")`.Also where are you loading the list before access it?

Comment: Does encoded list name work? i.e. Forms%20-%20May

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was in the destination. Editing the following lines worked:

```
List forms = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Forms - May");
string destination = "Forms  May/Folder1"; //kept 2 spaces
```

Looks like you can have a hyphen in the folder though... The following also works

```
List forms = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Forms - May");
string destination = "Forms  May/Folder1 - May";
```

Comment: Hi @cooper If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Comment: Hi @cooper i'm facing the same issue , cant able to add - symbol in folder name as well as cant get the folder by serverrelativeurl where the folder has the - symbol , i tried your code but it doesn't help me out can you give the clear idea on this